# Having issue with Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

**Here is my code: JS PART**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#parent").hide();
    $(".parentcheck").click(function(){
            if($(this).val()==="1") 
            {
                $("#parent").show();
                $('#switch').attr('disabled', '');

            }
            else {
                $("#parent").hide();
                $('#switch').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            }
    });

    $("#switch").change(function () {
    var selectedSwitch = $("#switch").val();
    var parentcheck = $(".parentcheck:checked").val();
    if (selectedSwitch!='' && selectedSwitch!='0'){
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url : "optionsgenerator.php",
    data: {menu: selectedSwitch},
    success: function(result, status, xResponse){
        if (result!=''){
            if($('#parentcheck').attr('checked')){
                $("#parent").hide();
            }
            else {
                $("#parent").html(result);
                $("#parent").show();
            }
        }
        else{
            alert('Error occured.');
            $("#parent").hide();
        }
    },
    error: function(e){
        alert(e);
    }
    });
    }
    else
    $("#parent").hide();
});

});
```

**And HTML Markup**

```
<select name="switch" id="switch">
<option value="" selected="selected">Select one...</option>
<option value="1">a</option>
<option value="2">b</option>
<option value="0">no one</option>
</select>

<div class="parent">
<input type="radio" class="parentcheck" name="parentcheck" value="0"/>
<input type="radio" class="parentcheck" name="parentcheck" value="1"/>

<select name="parent" id="parent"></select>
</div>
```

**The problems is**

If value of radio button with class `"parentcheck"` is **1**, my js shows selectbox without checking if it has something to show (in my case options returned from backend php code) or not

**I'm trying to achieve following**

If value of radio button with class `"parentcheck"` is **1** then `show`
selectbox  `#parent` **ONLY if ajax has already returned something**, **enable** selectbox `#switch`

Comment: For the selected switch part of it not working. YOu need to do the `&&` operate rather then or. Because it will get to the `selectedSwitch!=''` and realise that it equals 0 and it will pass it. So try using `&&` and that should fix that part

Comment: can your first problem be solved by using && instead of ||.  if the value is '0' this condition will evaluate to be true.

Comment: Thx for fast reply. please help to resolve last 2 problems. updated question. Take a look

Comment: WHat's wrong with my question, downvoter trolls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to get parentcheck by id, but parentcheck is a class:

```
var parentcheck = $("#parentcheck:checked").val();
```

try to change it to

```
var parentcheck = $(".parentcheck:checked").val();
```

EDIT:
for the unselecting:

```
       if($(this).val()==="1") 
        {
            if ($("#parent option").length > 0) {
                 $("#parent").show();
            }
            $('#switch').attr('disabled', '');

        }
        else {
            $("#parent").hide().find('option:selected').removeAttr('selected');
            $('#switch').attr('disabled', 'disabled').find('option:selected').removeAttr('selected');
        }
```

Comment: Thx for fast reply. ok. it was typo too but doesn't resolve anything. please help to resolve last 2 problems. updated question. Take a look

Comment: It doesn't deselect currently selected option of `#switch` and `#parent` selectbox

Comment: ok. second problem has gone too. left last third one. i'm gratefull. thx. BTW upvote my question so that i can upvote your answer too

Comment: Editor gives message `if $("#parent option").length > 0) {` syntax error. @Jlange suggested to  set a boolean flag in AJAX function, and then in the click listener only enable the selectbox if(flag). It sounds like good idea. Can you please realize it.. I'm newbie to js. Can't figure it out

Comment: i wrote "if $("#parent option").length > 0) {".... change to 
"if ($("#parent option").length > 0) {"

Comment: Can we chat via skype or any other im, there is 1 problem still. i wanna duscuss with you

Comment: it will take long. if you have any im for live discussion give me. or maybe skype

Comment: I don't have any of that... we could use google talk alonsenderovitz@gmail.com

Comment: you're offline mate. i'm sending messages. no response

Comment: Let's say i've selected value '1' option from #switch selectbox (.parentcheck's value currently 0). Then switched radio .parentcheck to value 1. #parent menu appears. All right. Then switched radio .parentcheck back to value 0. The #parent menu disappears. Good. Now, when i switch to 1 after that moment, js enables selectbox #switch to default state 0, BUT #parent shows options from ajax request. It must bw hidden (because there is no no result for empty value.) Why?

Comment: in your ajax call - "if($('#parentcheck').attr('checked')){", try to cange it to "if($('.parentcheck:checked').val() !== '1'){"

Comment: please add me. turalsemail@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

Solutions:

1)

```
 if(selectedSwitch != '' && selectedSwitch !=0)
```

- you are shorting your OR statement, needs to be an AND.

2)

```
$(".parentcheck").click(function(){
        if($(this).val() == "1") 
        {
            $('#parent).show();
            $('#switch').attr('disabled', '');

        }
        else {
            $('#parent').val('');
            $('#parent').hide();
            $('#switch').val("Select one...");
            $('#switch').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
});
```

- To set the value of the select, you need to give it the actual value of the index you want.

3) Set a boolean flag in your AJAX function, and then in the click listener only enable the selectbox if(flag).

Comment: 3 doesn't change. WHy not to set $('#switch').val(""); too? and 3rd answer is not clear. i'm newbie to js

Comment: ok. second problem has gone too. left last third one. i'm gratefull. thx. BTW upvote my question so that i can upvote your answer too

Comment: Are you there? Your idea sounds good. PLease help to realize it for 3rd problem

Comment: Looks like they have directed you in the right direction. Please pastebin your current state and your current question(s)